# Collect user data via Social Media Login

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way in Marketing Cloud to send users an email or Cloud Page form with a login to social media? Then we can pull basic information like Name, Email, Phone from their profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there were, don't do it. That's basically like stealing their password. Almost every social media site has tools that are designed to help you with stuff like this. Learn how to use their tools.

1. https://apps.twitter.com/
2. https://developers.facebook.com/
3. https://www.instagram.com/developer/
4. etc...

Comment: Thank you for the response. I wasn't sure how to go about this and was asked to research the capabilities. I wasn't finding any Marketing Cloud documentation and sought advice here. That makes sense about the issues. I'll recommend considering other options instead.